# How to combine multiple lstm layers for one output?

Tags: python-3.x, lstm

I am trying to find what is the best way to combine and train three different LSTM layers for one output.
Any sample code reference would be helpful.

I have three data set and I am trying to predict the risk of heart attack.

```
w = [age, weight]
h = [age, height]
risk = [ age, riskOfHeartAttack]
output = chanceOfHeartAttack

    heightModel = LSTM(...)
    weightModel = LSTM(...)
    riskModel = LSTM(...)
    combined = Sequential()
    combined concatenate([heightModel, weightModel,riskModel], axis=-1)
```

But this gives an error

All inputs to the layer should be tensors.

setup of different layers -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNdPE.png